Review my power MOSFET motor control circuit

Software engineer dabbling in electronics here.
I created this circuit to control a linear actuator using the states: Full speed forward, full speed backward, and off.
The switches S1 and S2 are pins on a raspberry pi.
The MOSFETs T1 thru T4 are suitably rated N-channel MOSFETs.
M is a DC motor that can be driven with +12 V (forward) and -12 V (backward). Other speeds not needed.
R1 and R2 and 1M resistors to discharge the MOSFET gates.
All connections to the 12 V power supply go through a single fuse rated 3 A, the motor draws 2 A.
An interlock preventing the opening of both switches simultaneously with a bit of safety margin is implemented in software (not perfect but seems okay, a bug would blow the fuse preventing catastrophic failure).
I think this is okay, the resistance of each MOSFET is sufficient to keep each circuit closed when the corresponding switch is in the 'off' state.
But I'm green, did I miss anything?

Are your switches driven with PWM? Full speed, ok ... but within what time? Current may be too high ...

you shouldn't ask for a review of a circuit without attaching the schematic.

"did I miss anything?" Yep the schematic you are referring to.

@Lundin Hahahaha. Yeah sorry. Fixed

@Antonio51 The motor draws 2A at peak, and the mosfets are rated 50A.

This question is superseded by revision to, based on your feedback. Thanks, everyone! https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/710148/8937

Basically it's highly naïve and fails to understand how a MOSFET works. The problem in a nutshell is that the upper MOSFETs are driven as source followers and, given that the gate voltage cannot be higher than 5 volts, then the source cannot switch to a voltage higher than 5 volts minus the gate-source threshold voltage. This means maybe 2 to 4 volts peak on the output.
It's not worth reviewing anything else about it because it'll perform so badly that it just isn't worth any more effort. Having said that, it's a regular rookie/newbie mistake so, you are in company.

So maybe the best solution is that they switch this with some "H bridge" motor driver IC with all of this built-in? Including overcurrent protection and other goodies like that.

@Lundin it's got to be the right one but yes, for sure. Or, depending on the MOSFET type they may get away with an 18 volt control signal.

@Lundin I'll look up an H bridge IC! Rolling my own would be nice for learning reasons but is not required.
Andyaka Thanks for the feedback! Holding back for now until I understand what you wrote

@cmc just ask if something is not graspable.

@Andyaka Thanks!!! - Oh, so for T1 to be common source and hence 5V switchable, I would need to place M on the drain side, but then the rest of the design won't work.

@cmc that's why we use specialist top-side MOSFET drivers that can take the gate above 12 volts so that source and drain on the upper MOSFETs can be truly down to a few milli ohm resistance when activated. If you want the source to reach the drain voltage then the gate needs to rise several volts higher than the drain voltage and, by inference, it will be several volts higher than the source = activation. All you are missing in this area is the ability to drive the upper MOSFET gates a few volts (possible ten) higher than the 12 volt supply.

Or I could replace T1 and T2 with 3V-threshold P-channel MOSFETs to have the required high side switches.

You could but then you might get problems with shoot-through because, for a small instant in time an upper and lower side MOSFET pair will both be partially on and you might destroy one of them.

What if I controlled each mosfet individually software, opening the mosfet closer to ground first?
Alternatively, could I introduce capacitors to introduce a slight delay in the switching of T1 and T2.

We are at the point where a schematic is needed for this new idea. It might be more productive to raise a new post at this point (make it open to the whole floor) so, @cmc if we are done here, please take note of this: What should I do when someone answers my question. If you are still confused about something then leave a comment to request further clarification.

Oh I was going to edit this one, but a new one makes more sense. My currently favored idea: T1,T2 as p-channels driven by small N-channels, rest as-is, schematic coming up in new post.

rev to is here! https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/710148/8937

rev3 is here! https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/710511/8937
