Review my power MOSFET motor control circuit - rev2

Software Engineer dabbling in electronics here. Looking to create a simple "jelly bean part" motor driver using MOSFETs to have an alternative to an IC like the DRV8825. This is revision 2 based on feedback from previous question.
F is a 2A fuse.
R1 - R4 are 100k pulldown resistors.
Q1 and Q2 are P-channel power MOSFETs switching the motor in high configuration with opposite polarity.
Q3 and Q4 are N-channel logic-level power MOSFETs closing the circuit for Q1 and Q2, respectively.
Q5 and Q6 are N-channel logic-level low-current MOSFETs to drive Q1 and Q2 in the high position.
M is a linear acuator motor that draws about 1.5A, polarity determines direction.
No protective diodes are used because Q1-Q4 are several times over-rated (cost was same).
MCU is a raspberry pi, O1 and O2 are output pins. Software prevents pins O1 and O2 going high within a few tens of ms of each other.
Because of over-rating and pause between switch, I suspect shoot-through will not be an issue.

Is this a reasonable design overall?
Do you spot any issues?


4-way crossover/short above Q1.

@winny Fixed, thanks

No, it's not a reasonable design. Q5 and Q6 are source followers so Q1 and Q2 will be on all the time.

@Finbarr Right, thanks!

The circuit configuration is called a ‘h bridge’ so convention would say to draw it as such. Ie: Q1,4 vertically aligned with Q2,3 with the motor horizontal between these two - looking like a ‘H’. Fuses are to protect the wire, they are too slow to protect the semiconductors. Consider adding a current limit circuit to avoid smoke. The body diodes of many mosfets are rather weak, so consider adding diodes. At the current level, I’d be using an integrated solution rather than rolling my own.

@Kartman incorporated feedback in rev3! https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/710511/8937

@Finbarr fixed in https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/710511/8937

@Kartman Thank you!!! rev 5 is up https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/710996/8937
