Review my power MOSFET motor control circuit - rev5

Software engineer dabbling in electronics here. With feedback from the previous iterations, I think I have something I can put on a breadboard without putting silicon particulate matter into the air. Would you agree?
Q1 and Q2 are P-channel power MOSFETs that get switched by Q5 and Q6. Those are N-channel logic MOSFETs sensitive enough to be switched by 3.3V raspberry pi pins O1 and O2. Q3 and Q4 are N-channel power MOSFETs that get switched by Q1 and Q2, while Schottky flyback diodes D1-D4 take care of reverse current without bothering Q3 and Q4 gates or Q1-Q4 internal diodes. R1 and R2 are pullups for Q1 and Q2, R3-R6 are pulldowns.
Software on the raspi prevents O1 and O2 switching at the same time or within 100ms from each other, which is much more than would be needed to prevent shoot-through shorts.
I removed smoothing for now for simplicity but might re-add based on previous advice.
IC based solutions and advice are valid but out of scope, as this question is strictly about discrete solutions.
Did I forget anything? Do you spot any issues? Do you disagree with any part of the design?
Many thanks to all who shared or will share advice, I could never have learned so much so quickly without you.

Are you going to try to control the motor speed, or do you just want it to run full speed forward and reverse and stop?

For now, full speed only- I might adapt to PWM later.

You have drifted off from what I originally advised. This is your original circuit with my corrections to three of the MOSFETs (that were upside down) and, the removal of the flyback diodes: -

Then I gave your this advice: -

If you are careful on how you activate and deactivate the two control
lines (O1 and O2) you can use (for instance), Q3's drain to activate
Q2 (when its position is remedied). Same for the other side of the
H-bridge.

But it all seems to have gone wrong from that point so, I suggest you simulate what I've shown above and don't move forward to any other revision without simulation.

One difference was necessary, I originally thought O1 and O2 are 5V, but it's 3.3V, so I cannot drive Q3 and Q4 directly, as 4V are required. Driving Q1 and Q2 with 2 logic level n-chan, and then inverting your advice, seemed the lowest part count.

How does your current schematic (in your question) address that issue @cmc

Setting up kicad/ngspice simulation now to see for myself about the diodes. Received conflicting advice.

If conflicting device was made on this site, please link me to it @cmc

The BS170 threshold is 2V, so I can drive the (now) P-channel MOSFETs Q1 and Q2 with it,
as low side switch to pullups R1 and R2 . I didn't want the raspberry pi to have a common voltage source with the 12V for risk of error, and I didn't want a IC driver, so no high side N channels. I can't drive Q3 and Q4 with BS170 because they would be high side switches to the pulldowns R3 and R4. Or would they? I didn't want to use BJTs as drivers either if I  can avoid it.

Here is the conflicting advice: Note that when M3/M4 get turned off, there's some current flowing through the motor inductance. The diodes automatically turn on M1/M2 to neutralize motor current. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/710635/8937

@cmc I've left a comment on that answer suggesting he may be incorrect.

The low side mosfet drive is a clever way of thinking but I dont think it will work the way you want. If you havent started taking the time to design the circuit in LTSpice I highly recommend doing so. I was doing the exact same thing as you and I took my business there to save me the time of soldering everything up and blowing up components. Theres only so much a simulator can do so you have to take it with a grain of salt, but for beginner stuff I highly recommend it.
Anyways, Ok so the first few problems/comments. The high side mosfets are being driven somewhat properly, but the low side mosfets are going to have some issues. When any one high side mosfet turns on, the appropriate low side mosfet is going to turn on too. However, the low side mosfet that's directly under the high side mosfet will turn on too, causing shoot through.
When the high side mosfet turns on, BOTH sides of the motor become 12V for a brief moment until the appropriate low side mosfet turns on, so both low side mosfets try to turn on at the same time. The one with its gate on the other side of the motor turns on marginally slower so shoot through shouldn't be terrible, but its still not an ideal design.
One of the first major tools that helped me out with this kind of problem is learning what a Class AB Amplifier was.

(Electronics Tutorials, https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/amplifier/class-ab-amplifier.html)
This is a buffer made of an NPN and a PNP transistor stacked on top of each other. When the input signal is high, the NPN turns on and the PNP turns off, and the NPN becomes an emitter current amplifier where a small input current has a massive output current, dumping current straight into the load. When the input signal goes low, the NPN off and the PNP turns on, where a small amount of current being sucked out of the PNP causes a massive amount of current to be sucked out of the load. This is very very useful, as we are driving a capacitor where both of those things need to happen.
The one stumbling block that immediately occurs is that we are using a 3.3V logic source. There are almost certainly better ways to amplify voltage than the one I'm about to list, but its discrete and very easy, so it should be suitable here. The BJT Voltage Amplifier will save the day in this case, as BJT transistors only need 0.7V to turn on.

(Wikipedia, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_emitter)
(I'm sorry this pic is so big I don't know how to make it smaller)
3.3V is plenty, so as long as you have a suitable input resistor (1k-10k), this will work fine. Note that this will invert the signal, so you will have to flip it in code, but that should be fine. This circuit amplifies your input voltage (0-3.3V) to (0-VCC).
So, if you want to drive your mosfets with 12V logic, you can run your MCU into a voltage amplifier to bring it to 12V if that's your VCC, then run that signal into the Class AB amplifier above, which will turn it into a (0.7-11.3V) possible source with loads and loads of output current possibility. This will help your mosfets switch faster and greatly reduce losses.
The best part is that the output of the Class AB amplifier can go to your High AND Low side mosfet gates at the same time! It doesn't work like that for voltages higher than 20, but for 12V it should do just fine. So, if you make two Class AB amplifiers and two BJT Voltage amplifiers on both sides, you can run them into the gates of each 'side' of the H bridge, and run it off of two pins on a RasPi.
Just for note: On the input/base of the BJT voltage amplifier, use a 1-10k resistor. For the Rc on the collector, also use a 1-10k resistor. On the input of the Class AB circuit, you should also add a 1-10k resistor, and you can add a 10Ohm resistor to the output of the amplifier, called a Gate Resistor. Most places recommend you add it to prevent ringing at the mosfet gate pin, and it would probably be a good idea.

Oh. So O1 goes to high, Q5 closes, Q1 closes- but D3 takes a very short moment to open, and during this time, Q3 closes too. Correct?

The changes you suggested are in fact not required, it works fine with just the mosfets. working version is up! https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/712521/8937

The 100k (R1..R4) are too high in value -- the FETs will be relatively slow in turning off (perhaps 100's of us; depends on the particular FET you use). You mentioned 100 ms non-overlap time -- this will work, but is probably excessive.
A higher performance design might use 1k resistors, and perhaps 10 us non-overlap time.
You don't need the schottkys -- there is no real problem letting the body diodes of the FETs conduct.
Likely you don't want the C across the motor. When the motor changes direction, this will act as a short across the supply and cause large glitches.
Are you trying to control motor speed (e.g. PWM in each direction), or just control motor direction ? For PWM, you don't really want to switch polarity at each PWM cycle - just stop driving for the PWM off time.

Thank you for the great input!!! Full speed forward/backward only so far, future PWM iteration possible. Trying to get simulation working, until then, do you see shoot through potential?

No; you likely won't have a shoot through problem.
To simulate the motor itself, you might use a large (1 F ?) capacitor in series with a resistor (this approximates the angular momentum of the motor), and a R in parallel with all which represents the losses (from friction). The value could be based on the no-load current consumption of the motor. Although the motor has windings, at this level you don't need an inductance in the model

working version is up! https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/712521/8937
