Review my power MOSFET motor control circuit - rev3

Software engineer dabbling in electronics. Based on previous feedback, here's my latest revision of a simple fully discrete motor driver.
MCU is a raspberry pi with GND output pins O1 and O2.
Q1 and Q2 are P-channel power MOSFETs driven by logic-level N-channel MOSFETS Q5 and Q6. R1 and R2 pull up Q1 and Q2 to 12V unless Q5 or Q6 are open, in which case ground opens Q1 or Q2.
Q3 and Q4 are N-channel power mosfets. O1 going high opens Q1 and Q4, O2 opens Q2 and Q3.
R5 pulls down Q5 and Q4 when O1 is low. R6 pulls down Q3 and Q6 when O2 is low.
D1-D4 serves as flywheel diodes to handle reverse motor current when breaking.
C is large capacitor to smooth out motor speed changes.
Software makes sure O1 and O2 are never on at the same time, and that there is a dead time in between.
PWM is optionally used to throttle motor speed.
Do you see any issues?
Is the design okay?
Thanks!!!

Q1 is upside down. So is Q4 and Q6: -

Once you have corrected the MOSFET positions, the external diodes (D1 to D4) won't be needed due to the internal bulk diodes in the H-bridge MOSFETs.
You also need to add component values and link data sheets to the MOSFETs.
If you are careful on how you activate and deactivate the two control lines (O1 and O2) you can use (for instance), Q3's drain to activate Q2 (when its position is remedied). Same for the other side of the H-bridge.

Use Q3's drain to activate Q2- so use the N-channels as drivers for the P-channels instead of having dedicated little ones. Mind blown- seems straight forward enough to set up.

rev 4 is up https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/710627/8937

Thank you!!! rev 5 is up https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/710996/8937

As the processor's outputs toggle and drive the (relatively large) gate capacitance of the MOSFETs, there will be a brief interval when (e.g.) Q1 an Q3 are on.
This will consume very large current spikes, and either cause damage (from high voltages induced in the power wires as the cross conduction stops; cause resets in your processor (if powered from the same supply), or cause brief bursts of RF oscillation.
You need a 'real' non-overlap control of the MOSFETs.

I intended to account for this by having a period defined in software where O1 and O2 are botj low. Can you kindly explain how this would be insufficient?

I would still prefer this protection in the circuit, can it be done with discreet components?

Not quite "discrete" but you could use logic gates to drive the MOSFETs and change your drive signals to e.g. ON and DIRECTION.

@Finbarr that sounds really good!

Thank you!!! rev 5 is up https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/710996/8937

Current spikes do not seem to be an issue: working version is up. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/712521/8937
