Review my power MOSFET motor control circuit - rev6 - it works! (or does it?)

Software engineer dabbling in electronics here. Based on copious amounts of feedback from this community (and purchasing a copy of 'Art of Electronics, 3rd edition') it seems to work!
Q1 and Q2 are P-channel power MOSFETs in the high position switched by Q5 and Q6 which are n-channel logic MOSFETs driven by 3.3V raspi output. Q3 and Q4 are driven by Q1 and Q2 to form an h-bridge circuit.
Transient simulation using alternating +3.3V pulses on O1 and O2 reveal expected current levels at Q3 and Q4 (back-current is presumably omitted from motor model at inverse polarity) and no sign of shorts or large spikes of flyback current.
Input voltage

Red is O1, blue is O2
Output voltage

Brown is M1+, yellow is M1-
output current

Blue is Q3 drain, Purple is Q4 drain.
Seeing there was a chance of not starting a fire I set it up on a breadboard, and after fixing some errors with the FET pinouts the correct voltage showed up on the multimeter (O2 to +12V pictured)

So I hooked up the pi and the motor- and it moves.

Output pins on the pi were chosen that are pulled low by the pi during boot-up and before initialization.
So now that I have a first seemingly working and not obviously dangerous version:
Thanks to everyone!

Am I missing anything a bit more subtle that could bite me later?
How could the design be improved?

Previous discussion:

ICs are fine but off-topic
The power fet diodes are sufficient to handle flyback
Shootthrough is avoided without special precautions
PWM is currently not used, just forward and backward


Your transient analysis graph would be better stacked vertically with control inputs at the top, voltage outputs in the middle and motor current at the bottom. All lined up vertically. I'm unsure what O1 and O2 refer to in the schematic.

@Andyaka Added as described!

Ha ha no LOL. You need to have them lined up and scaled together. One image with all the waveforms captured simultaneously. No waveforms overlapping at all. A much finer pen and, allow the waveforms to be captured with special attention to having a small maximum timestep to get better temporal resolution.

Will do! Will take a while, I need to learn how to do that in kicad and get a portable scope for my closet lab to get some real data as well.

You do have a problem with shoot-through. You just don't know it. And you won't know it by only operating the bridge as an electronic forward/reverse switch because the transistors are eating the (infrequent) transient. In other words, every time you switch from forward to reverse or vice versa, there will be cross conduction that causes a little bit of heat due to a very brief short circuit.
This isn't a problem operating the way you are operating the device because the transistors can tolerate this. If, however, you want to do speed control with this bridge, those tiny short circuits accumulate thousands of times a second (your PWM switching frequency.)
A better way would be able to control the transistors independently with 2 additional GPIOs. That way, you can optimize the dead time between transitions in firmware.
If you don't have additional GPIOs for this function, as a compromise, you can add deadtime in hardware. However, with this approach, you will have a "hardwired" dead time that can't be configured in software.
You can also consider "adaptive" deadtime half-bridge and H-bridge gate drivers. Most also include the bootstrap to use all Nch MOSFETS for better efficiency due to lower RdsON.

Thanks!! I assume I will need higher resolution simulation or a scope to see this for myself...

Improvement:
Insert a voltage-follower buffer at the gate of each MOSFET (Q1 to Q4, not required yet for Q5, Q6). This can be as simple as two BJTs, an NPN & a PNP.  This will improve (speed up) the switching times.

Link for above image:
Drive a MOSFET via BJT?
Shoot-through:
I suspect you will still have some degree of "shoot-through" occurring.  This probably won't be a real problem until you increase switching frequency into the kHz range.
To check for shoot-through without a current probe: put your scope voltage probes at the gate of each MOSFET of the same pole, eg: Q1 & Q3.  Shoot-through will occur when both Q1 & Q3 are on simultaneously, ie: when Q3 gate > 2V, AND Q1 gate < (12 - 2)= 10V.
An alternative method: place a resistor of one-tenth the resistance of the motor between the power supply & your motor driver.  Monitor the voltage at the motor driver end of this resistor with a scope voltage probe.  If thus voltage deviates from supply voltage by more than 10% then you have shoot-through.
Problem:

If yellow really is the voltage at M1-, then you have a problem.  It should be very similar to the red trace, M1+, ie: it should be square, not curved at the top of the waveform.

Thank you! I somehow assumed shoot through would manifest as much higher current spikes. It also seems now would be a good time to get a scope.

@cmc  Huh?  You don't have a scope?  What generated those waveforms?

Those are from kicad/ngspice simulation. The difference in waveform depending on polarity seems to come from the motor model.

Re: shoot-thru. Yes, these are very high current spikes that pass from the DC supply through both MOSFETs in one arm simultaneously, but which bypass the load (motor).  These can be detected by various means, a couple of which I have mentioned in my answer.

Waveforms: suggest posting new waveforms, showing all of them on the same plot, so that they are all aligned in time.  We need to be able to line up all the vertical edges, these indicate times at which the switching events occur.

Will do! Requested by @Andyaka as well. Will take a while, need to learn how to do that in kicad, and get a good portable scope for my office lab to have real data as well.

I don't use kicad, so I can't help you with that.  Suggest get a 4 channel scope, not 2 channel.\

Thanks for the advice! I have heard elsewhere as well that 4-channel is preferred

Well, I would prefer 8 or even 16 channel myself... but they are a little rare.. :-)
